How to fail a test for an api call if json brackets are not empty
I have a Pytest script making a HTTP call:
def test_bid_submission_send():
# Act:
response = post_requests(token, '/xxx/api/xxx/bidsubmissions/send',
                         setpayload_bidsubmissions_send(powerplantId))
# Assert:
assert not response.json()["error"]
assert response.status_code == 200  # Validation of status code

The response is
{"success":[],"error":[{"hpsId":10037,"powerPlant":{"name":"Saurdal","id":16606,"regionId":20,"priceArea":2,"timeSeries":null,"units":[]}}]}

I want to fail the test if the
"error":[]

has content (which it has in my example above)
If the
"success":[]

has content I would like to pass the test

assert not response["error"]?

Not it fails if i put in assert not response["error"] AND if I put in assert not response["success"], for both. It is more like I want the [] for the error json object to be empty and then the test is successfull. So if the response is like my example in the questin it should fail.

It's unclear to me what your problem is. Can you perhaps show what you tried, what works and what fails?

edited my question now. Hope it is more understandable.


I want to fail the test if the
"error":[...]

j = response.json()
assert len(j["error"]) == 0


if the
"success":[]
has content I would like to pass the test

assert len(j["success"]) != 0

